# How to get Video thumbnail from URL

Tags: android, url, thumbnails, libraries, video-thumbnails

I am trying to generate a thumbnail of the video. But I cannot use Glide as it colliding with other gallery libraries. 
I have tried Picasso that is not giving me thumbnail from the URL. `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail` is working in my code but it is too slow.

Can someone suggest any effective tool or technique, to get the thumbnail from the URL in java??

Comment: Did you try this https://medium.com/@mujjtahidah/get-thumbnail-video-from-url-android-f71533168228

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MediaMetadataRetriever` class. For example

```
   private fun getThumbNail(uri: Uri): Bitmap {
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)

    return retriever.frameAtTime //or frameAtPosition(..)/frameAtIndex(..)
   }
```